# Grouping two columns and storing in one column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group two columns in data frame and store to the another column with different name.

Example:

[image]

From above table I want to **group** **source** and **destination city** into one column and **store in another column with different name.**

I have tried but its not working. My code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Dataset.csv")
group_data = df.groupby(['source_city','destination_city'])
```

Its not working. **Please anyone help me with this**

Comment: Maybe `df['Path'] = df['source_city'] + ' - ' + df['destination_city']`?

Comment: Do you mean just combine them into one? like `df["New_Column"] = df.source_city+ " " + df.destination_city`?